# OnResume() is not called of the home activity when back pressed from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am working on an android application. I have cardviews for multiple fragemnts. I have put these cardviews in the main activity. So when I pressed the cardview a fragment will open. So i will make these cardviews visibility as gone. But on back press the onResume() is not called. Hence the layout is not getting visible. I tried many things but did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] illustrating what you are asking about. Show the minimal amount of code you can in an activity and a few fragments. For app development, I find it incredibly helpful to create a new project with some dummy fragments to figure this stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an activity with a fragment. Then you load a new fragment and then you press back. This interaction will not fire the activity's `onResume()` because the activity has never been stopped. If there is logic you need to perform between fragments, it needs to be somewhere else. I cannot provide any more details without some more information.

Comment: I have created a layout of five cards in the main activity which i make invisible when fragment is called. I need to make the layout visible when the fragment is closed. I just tried to make the layout visible in onPause() of the fragment. It worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all use the navigation on Android Jetpak